# How to display a list of Menu Items in a table along with Buttons?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to list a Menu from a String array containing ItemName and price.I used table layout for this.From this table the user shall select the quantity he wants to order by using a number picker for each item(row). Also a Confirm button is there for Confirming the order after selecting the quantity.

Problem 1- As I am dynamically filling the table from String array the Confirm button which I placed as static is appearing at the first Row and the data rows are only coming after the Confirm button.Is it possible to use another layout for these buttons and table layout for only the Menu Items?.I tried a different layout for it but the button got disappeared.

Problem 2- Upon clicking confirm button the menu items which are selected should be passed to the next activity for processing. How can i make this possible?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: It would help us help you if you would post the code you've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a [Custom Component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) that contains all the elements from a row in your table (Name of the product, number picker, confirm button etc). Then use a listview and fill it with instances of that custom component. This will hopefully solve a lot of your problems and make your code a bit easier to follow.

Try something similar to this guide:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Good luck!